# Using Top distinction with output parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to use a top distinction with an output parameter in SQL?
I am trying to use the below code and getting a syntax error:

```
@returnParam int output = 0

Select @returnParam = top 1 Id 
From table
Where xyz
```

Whereas taking out the top 1 the query has no errors.  I could probably nest the query to get the top 1 from an inner query, but I don't think that is ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
@returnParam int output = 0

Select top (1) 
    @returnParam =  Id 
From table
Where xyz
```

Put the `TOP (1)` first - before the assignment to the output parameter.

You can find this (and much more) in the [**official** MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) (the "SQL Server Books Online" - freely available to *anyone!*)

Comment: thank you this solved it! also, honorable mention to Rahul who cam in only 24 seconds after your answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit syntax issue with your query. It should be

```
Select top 1 @returnParam =  Id 
From table
Where xyz;
```